# Will changing the 'Plugin Name' header in the next update of a plugin break anything?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a small plugin on wordpress.org with a few thousand downloads.

It has a typo in the Plugin Header, "Plugin Name". I want to fix this in the next update. Will changing the "Plugin Name" in the plugin header have any negative effects on the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer: Changing the 'Plugin Name' does not effects the plugin.